# jscript ui steps calculation and logic problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to create a VPS style slider selector using jQuery UI but I'm not able to find the correct "max" and "step" numbers, I need only 6 steps, starting from 0, so I have used:

```
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 6,
step: 1,
value: 0,
```

but it is not working as I have expected. The selector cursor is working odd when I click on it, I know is is something with the max and the step value because using an example I did find with max:576 and step 56.8 is working fine most probably have something to do with the rule in the UI docs where the min-max value have to be divisible by the step value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont know, if i correctly understand you. 
If you jast want a slider with snap to increments and value between 0 and 6 you should do so:

```
$('your-slider-selector').slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 6,
        step: 1});
```

And thats all!

Comment: Thanx! I did that but the slider was acting odd....after investigating i found the problem was the jquery version, with any other version that 1.3.2 the slider is acting odd. Thanx again!